# sqlalchemy and one to many: why does the child have a parent_id attribute?

Tags: python, database, database-design, sqlalchemy

I'm going through the sqlalchemy [Relationship Configuration](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many) docs. The example for the one-to-many bidirectional relationship looks like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

My understanding is that `backref="parent"` in the `Parent` class gives the `Child` class a `Child.parent` attribute that links back to the original `Parent` object.

What I then don't understand is why the `Child` object still explicitly needs the `parent_id` attribute? Isn't that doubling up information? Is it making it quicker to query the database or does it have some other benefits? Perhaps I am misunderstanding how the bidirectional one-to-many relationship works to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `children` and `parent` attributes created by the `relationship` are only available in the "python world" of your application.

In contrast, the two `id` columns and the `parent_id` column are actual columns (the only ones in this example) in the database.
So when you access a parent like `child.parent`, sqlalchemy looks up the child's `parent_id` and retrieves the `Parent` with this id from the database.
The other way round, for `parent.children`, sqlalchemy finds all `Children` instances with a matching `parent_id`.

So there's no duplication of information.
You can regard the `children` and `parent` attributes as convenience functions, doing the database logic for you.

Comment: Thanks @sebastian. So without the `parent_id` the relationship wouldn't work, yes? How does `child.parent` look up`parent_id`? Is it looking through columns that have `parent` as a foreign key? Or is there a naming convention that I missed?

Comment: Yep, the `parent_id` column is the crucial piece of information that makes a child a child of a certain parent. SQLAlchemy uses `parent_id` since it's declared as a `ForeignKey('parent.id')` - declaring that `parent_id` matches the `parent.id`, the `id` column in the `parent` table.

Comment: Cheers! That makes sense now I think